# Determining what's the slowest component of the server windows 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, configuration

I'm trying to determine what needs to be upgraded on my server.
When doing some load testing I saw that the processor spiked to 100% . But how can I determine if the hdd might need an upgrade too ?

What tools can I use ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The native [Performance Monitor (perfmon)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490957.aspx) utility that comes with Server 2003 should suffice. Add the appropriate counters to your monitor and that should supply you with the metrics you need to judge whether or not you need to upgrade your HD as well as your processor.

Comment: Using perfmon is not enough, you need to know **how** to use it. Especially when there are thousands of possible counters to consider, [a bit of guidance](http://www.it-etc.com/2010/04/14/use-perfmon-to-monitor-servers-and-find-bottlenecks/) is surely welcome.